# Best Unit Test Framework for Windows Azure Solutions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, azure, nunit

I am looking for framework options to unit test a windows azure solution.
There are total 5 worker roles. A chain of worker roles that trigger processing based on messages in Azure queues and use Azure Table Storage as intermediary database between worker roles and the final output is written to Blob Storage.
What would be the best way to deal with this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of unit testing framework should be completely agnostic to the fact that you're using Azure queues and table storage. Unit tests are for testing *your code*, not how your code interacts with other services. Part of writing unit testable code is making sure that any logic interesting enough to be worth unit testing is sufficiently decoupled from the external service to be able to test it without the external service.

You'll usually still want to have tests that include the external surface, but they're going to be inherently more brittle, more time consuming to execute, and more time consuming to root cause failures from, so you generally want to keep them separated and run them a bit less frequently.

Now, if you're working in a code base that hasn't been written with this level of testability in mind, the ways in which you need to mock out your interactions with Azure will play into your choice of mocking framework (which may or may not be the same as your unit testing framework). But I'm not going to get into specific choices of framework since that can't really be answered objectively - it's too opinion based a question to really be appropriate for Stack Overflow.